# QTP flight reservation application not able to enter the passenger name

Tags: qtp

I am new to QTP. In flight reservation application I am not able to enter the passenger name. I am using the following code:

```
Dialog("regexpwndtitle:=Flight Reservation").WinEdit("hwnd:=1246182").Set "sachin"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should not use `HWND` as part of the description, the `HWND` of an object is different every time the test is run so you won't find the object in subsequent runs. Try recording the application to see what properties are typically used for description or you can use the **Object Spy** in order to find better properties to use.

I would recommend using *attached text* for `WebEdit`s.